# WPF: PropertyChanged (seems to be) creating an (infinite) loop

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I am getting an **"stack overflow"-Exception** when editing a property using `MVVM` and a `ListView`.

My ViewModel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

I am working on a 'Calender'. In each day of this 'calender', there are two files I can access depending on the day that I'm currently looking at, the two files are converted into two lists of strings in my ViewModel, one is 'Schedule' and the other is 'Notes'. They are both stored in ListViews on the UI.

The user can **select**, **add**, **remove**, and **edit** items. The user can select which action he/she wants, and it gets stored on a property called `SelectedEditingAction`.

The `SelectedSchedule` and `SelectedNote` of my `ViewModel` are associated with the **Selected Item** of the `Schedule` and `Notes` ListViews respectively.

When the user selects an item on either ListView the corresponding SelectedItem property changes.

- If it's value is not -1, the method `ActivateEditingActions` gets called, passing the `selected value (int)`.
- If it's a Schedule (bool):

  - `ActivateEditingAction` gets called with false from the `SelectedNote` property.
  - `ActivateEditingAction` gets called with true from the `SelectedSchedule` property.

**SelectedNote Property:**

```
    public int SelectedNote
    {
        get
        {
            return -1;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != -1) 
                ActivateEditingAction(false, value);
            // I don't set to an underlying field here,
            // I always want this to be -1, but I can 
            // pass in the value to ActivateEditingAction 
            // that the ListView WANTS me to set to a field

            // - Not sure if this is bad code practice
        }
    }
```

**ActivateEditingAction**

```
    private void ActivateEditingAction(bool isSchedule, int selectedItem)
    {
        if (SelectedEditingAction == "Nothing")
            return;

        switch (SelectedEditingAction)
        {
            case "Add Items": AddItemToListView(isSchedule); break;
            case "Remove Items": RemoveSelectedItemFromListView(isSchedule, selectedItem); break;
            case "Edit Items": EditSelectedItemInListView(isSchedule, selectedItem); break;
            default: throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        base.OnPropertyChanged(isSchedule ? "Schedule" : "Notes");
    }
```

And, the methods that I'm working on (I'm doing the EditSelectedItemInListView later)

```
    private void AddItemToListView(bool isSchedule)
    {
        // Getting the new item
        string newItem = isSchedule ? 
                      "You have no schedule for this day." : 
                      "You have no notes for this day.";

        // Mutation
        if (isSchedule) _schedule.Add(newItem);
        else _notes.Add(newItem);
    }

    private void RemoveSelectedItemFromListView(bool isSchedule, int selectedItem)
    {
        // Confirming the action
        var confirm = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove this item?", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
        if (confirm != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            return;

        // Mutation
        if (isSchedule) _schedule.RemoveAt(selectedItem);
        else _notes.RemoveAt(selectedItem);

        // If the ListView doesn't have any more items, we don't want it to be empty!
        if ((isSchedule ? _schedule : _notes).Count == 0)
            AddItemToListView(isSchedule);
    }
```

Remove and Add seem to be working fine. **But I am getting an stack overflow when editing.**

When I have the **Add Editing** Action selected, then add an item to the selected list view, after finishing it goes back to `ActivatateEditingAction`, at the end I call `base.OnPropertyChanged(isSchedule ? "Schedule" : "Notes");` 
And then it gets into an infinite loop, causing a stack over flow.

So basically, what I THINK is happening (for some reason) is when I notify the property is changed, the ListView (shown here is the Schedule ListView)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Schedule}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
    Margin="0,5,0,0" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Row="1"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedSchedule}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemContainerStyle}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="15" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Updates the ItemsSource, causing (logically) the SelectedIndex to get reset to 0, thus setting the SelectedIndex property to 0, calling the `ActivateEditingAction` method (and it continues doing it over and over again), resulting in [this call stack and a stack over flow exception](https://gyazo.com/dd41dc597d4a23b492f76b5a36914367)

It seems the item keeps getting added, then it notifies the property it's changed, thus it's a problem.

I also have some issues with the Remove action. It works fine - until something strange with PropertyChanged happens.

I can remove all these items, [like in this example](https://gyazo.com/610527f8d2fd2ef6a44fba7d8dcdd3d6) (that is the List for Schedule)

When I get to the last item from the screenshot **ee**, and delete it it works fine, making a new copy like it's supposed to. The **Remove** action adds a new item "You have no schedule for today." into the list when the count of the collection is 0 or lower ( I find strange that the `AddItemToListView`  works here but not when is called from `ActivateEditingAction` )

The new automatically-made item is added to the respective list, but then it stops working. When I remove this item from the ListView, then, like the add item method, it gets to the base.OnPropertyChanged(), calls it again, then when it finishes- he calls it again in the PropertyChanged method, and this happens over and over (This time it doesn't result in a Stack Over Flow because it pauses every time it asks you for if you are sure you want to do the remove action).

I'd also like you to note, these infinite loops only have happened after I remove all the items in the gyazo screenshot and get a new item in the Listview ("You have no schedule for today."), and it doesn't happen when I remove the last item that could be seen in the gyazo screenshot.
Which is strange.

**Why am I getting into infinite loops when updating the values or removing the last automatically added item?**

Comment: One advice - do not try to do everything at once !! start  with the most basic version & then start extending it.

Comment: +1 @Nikita. Welcome to SO Coffee, in general you'll have a much better chance of getting questions answered on this site if you post a full self-contained working example that people can cut-n-paste directly into VS. If you'd done that then you entire question could have been summed up in one sentence "Why does the following code result in a stack overflow and how do I fix it?" As it is at the moment there are large sections missing, and people on this site are usually too lazy to fill in the blanks for you. I'd suggest putting together a minimal example and trying again.

Comment: Yeah, at first I was trying to make it concise. Unfortunately, my writing style and general lack of knowledge on the topic and on how to make proper questions failed me in the end. Anyway, thanks, I'll try this again and keep it in mind. So just to get clear on what you suggested, I'll make this viewmodel and the view self-contained. So, for example- I replace all repositories that get their information from outer sources, and make them into constant variables, so the code is self-contained. I think that's what you mean, thanks anyway!

Comment: I tried cleaning up the text so the question is clearer. I am having issues understanding it though. I don't think both Collections are relevant, probably the issues happen even if you have only one of them, right? Can you add the Code for the `Schedule` or `Notes` properties? They are relevant to your question.

Comment: Eh, I wouldn't bother- Schedule and Notes receive from a private property on my ViewModel called DayFiles, that receives information from DayFilesRepository. A repository I use to get the two .txt files for the current day and convert them into a tuple of two Lists of string. Thanks anyway, I'm working on a more concise closed off code that isn't receiving it's information from files, just from constant values. So it can demonstrate the problem without the trouble of copying my whole project.

Comment: BTW: if ((isSchedule ? _schedule : _notes).Count == 0). Do NOT do this, it's really hard to read, if you're haven't looked at your code for a while.

Comment: When error is in Editing, then why you didn't post code for Editing ? What Adding/Removing code which you have posted has to do with your question ? You are saying you will work on Editing code later, then why this error ? Secondly, StackOverflow exceptions are thrown if you are using some LOOP, RECURSIVE binding.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict Make a workable version and post it to DropBox.com.

Comment: Change your Add/Edit/Delete logic to this : Use 3 buttons for Add/Edit/Delete. Select an item from ListView, then Press Edit/Delete button. For Addition, you can choose whether to Add new item to end, or at chosen index in the ListView.

Comment: You might be setting SelectedIndex of ListView from outside resulting in SelectionChanged event firing again and again.

Comment: Your design seems confusing and overly complex for a CRUD form. Sounds like all you need are 1) your list, source bound to the VM, from which something is selected in order to edit, 2) a ContentControl whose Content is bound to the SelectedItem of the list, and 3) DataTemplates containing editors for each Type of thing in the list, which are displayed by the ContentControl upon binding update.  You can send the selected item to the VM via the Parameter of the ICommand binding (e.g., the Save button in the editor).  No weird twiddling in the VM needed :/